# Which repository for sorting on a nested entity property using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I want to get sorted list of `Model`s for a given set of `Car` vins. The following repository query attempts to do this:

```
@Query("select distinct c.model"
        + "from Car c "
        + "where c.id in :vins")
public Set<Model> findDistinctModelForCarIdsIn(@Param("vins") Set<Integer> vins, Sort sort);
```

But it appears sort does not work if I put this in a `ModelRepository`:

```
http://localhost/api/models/search/findDistinctModelForCarIdsIn?vins=16203,25617,42661&sort=model.name,asc
```

If instead I put `findDistinctModelForCarIdsIn` in `CarRepository`, the sort works:

```
http://localhost/api/cars/search/findDistinctModelForCarIdsIn?vins=16203,25617,42661&sort=model.name,asc
```

Why is this? Is the rule to put the method in the repository corresponding to the entity that I selecting from (e.g., `Car`) instead of the what I'm selecting (e.g., `Model`)?

Here are my domain objects:

```
class Car {
  Integer id;

  @ManyToOne 
  Model model;
}

class Model {   
   Integer id;
   String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand the essence of the question, so I will try to give an answer.

As far as I know, for this type of query, sorting is applied as follows:

```sql
select distinct c.model
from Car c 
where c.id in :vins
order by c.{prod} {desc|asc}
```

An alias is taken from the **from section** and sorting is applied to it. In your case it is a `from Car c`. Alias is `c`.

In any case, I would advise you to enable the jpa debug mode using the following settings and look at the sql requests themselves

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've enabled the SQL logging and can see that an `ORDER BY` clause is missing when that `@Query` is in a `ModelRepository`.  I do see the `ORDER BY` clause when the `@Query` is in a  `CarRepository`. My question is why does it not work in the `ModelRepository`. If you can answer that question, I will accept and upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @James after a short debug, I found out that it doesn’t matter in which repository to write this request. But there is the following behavior, for my version of **spring boot 2.7.7**, the `select distinct` expectedly causes an `ERROR error: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list` for the query from the example. Therefore, I can only assume that in your case the `order by` is not added to the request, just to avoid this error.